# ReCaptchaV3 invalid csrf token on form submit - when storefront->csrf->mode = ajax

Tags: recaptcha, shopware, shopware6, recaptcha-v3

In my staging environment (Shopware 6.4.17.2 with Varnish cache installed), I see an exception during register form submit.

- ReCaptchaV3 is enabled
- SHOPWARE_HTTP_CACHE_ENABLED=0
- storefront->csrf->mode = **twig**
- storefront->reverse_proxy->enabled = false

in this case I see no errors

- ReCaptchaV3 is enabled
- SHOPWARE_HTTP_CACHE_ENABLED=0
- storefront->csrf->mode = **ajax** (correct setting for reverse proxy)
- storefront->reverse_proxy->enabled = false

I see a call to
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/reload?k=

And get invalid `csrf token error`, and no `/csrf/generate` call is sent.

Can you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your [site key](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/create-key) is missing from the request.

Look for an element with the class `captcha-google-re-captcha-v3` in the source code of your page and see if the `data-google-re-captcha-v3-options` attribute of the element contains the `siteKey`.

If you can't find it in the source code, did you set your credentials in the administration at `Settings > Basic Information > Captcha`?
You can also set them via the CLI:

```bash
bin/console system:config:set core.basicInformation.activeCaptchasV2.googleReCaptchaV3.isActive true
bin/console system:config:set core.basicInformation.activeCaptchasV2.googleReCaptchaV3.config.siteKey xxxxxx
bin/console system:config:set core.basicInformation.activeCaptchasV2.googleReCaptchaV3.config.secretKey xxxxxx
```

Comment: Yes site key is present, I trimmed it from the Url in the question.

Comment: Is the key present in the request to google or did you just omit it on purpose in your question?

Comment: Just omitted on purpose in my question. Site key is correctly set and I see validations on the reCaptcha panel